# Why is the GUI frozen while foreaching through a ListView and using GetStringAsync?

Tags: c#, json, multithreading, listview, httprequest

I'm using a foreach to go through ListView whose items are loaded from an XML file. Then I'm doing a asynchronous HTTPRequest with the item name to my webpage to get a JSON string, so far it works pretty well.

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

 foreach (ListViewItem item in lV_Items.Items)
  {
   JObject o = JObject.Parse(client.GetStringAsync("http://000.000.000/?item=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Text)).Result);
  }
```

Then I'm editing the new value from the JSON into the items SubItem

```
string amount= (string)o["amount"];
item.SubItems[1].Text = amount;
```

I'm running this code in a timer which repeats itself every minute. However, I'm struggling with performance optimizations since a few days even though I read a lot about for example ListView.BeginUpdate or putting the HTTPRequest in another thread. First of all, I don't quite understand why the GUI freezes while doing the foreach. Given the asynchronous HTTP Request which doesn't do its work on the main thread (at least I hope this is for what asynchronous stands for) it shouldn't freeze on the request. Also the operation of editing the SubItems should be pretty fast, especially because there are only about 10 items in the List.

I thought about loading the Items into a List (dynamic collection) instead of the ListView directly. Then I will run 1 timer which periodically sends the List to another Thread, then the Thread refreshes the values in the list and sends it back to the main form. In the Mainform there is a second timer which periodically puts the List into the ListView (just for visualization). Two timers because I think if will put both of the above into one timer the timer will wait till the thread is finished, resulting into still freezing the application.

I guess this is one idea, but there is a lot of untransparent work done and it's probably going to be harder to maintain / debug. Any ideas of how I should do it and what would be better would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: You're calling `.Result` on an async method, which means it will block.  Since this is happening in the UI, this is why it's freezing - you're not really making an asynchronous call.  I'd suggest either a background worker thread, or redoing your approach in the UI to truly leverage async/await.  Perhaps a second method that you call (and await) that does the foreach and makes the web calls.

Comment: Calling `.Result` on an async method is evil... :)

Comment: It took me so long but finally the program runs without freezing. Just because a single word. Thank you very much all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `client.GetStringAsync(...).Result`, you block until `GetStringAsync` completes, which defeats the purpose of using an async method. You should use `await` instead:

```
string json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://000.000.000/?item=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Text));
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
```

(note that you need to make your method `async`)